# Not able to set default values on Form Load in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

Basically I need to perform the http request by passing id. Once I get the response, I need to assign the values to the form fields.

I have tried using setValue & patchValue. But didn't work

spService

```
itemData = new ItemData()

    getItembyID(itemID) {
          return this.http.get<Object>(this.baseUrl +"items("+itemID+")")
          .pipe(map ((response : Response) => {
            const data = response['d']
            return data
          })
          ).subscribe((data : Response) => {
              this.setItemData(data)
          })
        }

    setItemData(data) {
        this.itemData.requestno  = data.Request_x0020_Number
        this.itemData.requestid  = data.Request_x0020_ID
```

edit-form.component.ts

```
constructor(private spService : SharepointService,
                  private formBuilder : FormBuilder)

 ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe((param : Params)=> {
            const id = param['ID']
            this.spService.getItemByID(ID)
       })

    this.itemData = this.sharepointService.itemData 
    // In console, I can see the details of the itemData but not able to set to the formcontrols.

    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       RequestNo : [''],
       RequestId : ['']
    })

    this.editForm.patchValue({
      RequestNo : this.itemData.requestno,
      RequestId : this.itemData.requestid

    })
    }   // End of OnInit
```

edit-form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]= "editForm">
  <label> DefaultRequestNo </label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="RequestNo">

   <label> DefaultRequestID </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="RequestId">

</form>
```

Comment: need to see the SharePointService and how / when itemData is populated.. if it is available synchronously then what you have here should work (though there is a cleaner way to accomplish it IMO)

Comment: In SharePoint service, i have itemData, getItemByID,setItemData methods. I have added SharePoint service code on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is that your itemData in your service is not available synchronously, but you're accessing it as though it is. You should set up a subject in your service that your component can subscribe to:

modified SP service:

```
  itemData = new ItemData();
  private itemDataSource = new ReplaySubject<ItemData>(1);
  itemData$ = this.itemDataSource.asObservable();

  getItembyID(itemID) {
    return this.http.get<Object>(this.baseUrl +"items("+itemID+")")
      .pipe(map ((response : Response) => {
        const data = response['d']
        return data
      })
      ).subscribe((data : Response) => {
          this.setItemData(data)
      })
  }

  setItemData(data) {
    this.itemData.requestno  = data.Request_x0020_Number;
    this.itemData.requestid  = data.Request_x0020_ID;
    this.itemDataSource.next(this.itemData);
  }
```

then you can subscribe in your component:

```
// just do this once
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   RequestNo : [''],
   RequestId : ['']
})

this.sharepointService.itemData$.subscribe(itemData => {
  this.itemData = itemData;
  this.editForm.setVale({
    RequestNo : this.itemData.requestno,
    RequestId : this.itemData.requestid
  });
});
```

the reason your logs are "lying" to you; in your service, you set an initial object value and then only ever mutate that object.  when you log an object in the console, it doesn't show you the 'point in time' value, it shows you the reference to that object and what values are at that reference, so even though the data isn't actually available when you attempt to set the form values, it still appears in your logs when it does eventually get set.

This is a one of many reasons why you should avoid object mutation in general in Javascript and instead instantiate a new object everytime you change something like:

```
  setItemData(data) {
    this.itemData = Object.assign({}, this.itemData, {
      requestno: data.Request_x0020_Number,
      requestid: data.Request_x0020_ID
    });

    this.itemDataSource.next(this.itemData);
  }
```

this method will ensure you are not mutating a new object and instead are creating a new object everytime.  This particular method may not be right for your use case, but the principle is the same, don't mutate.

Comment: Thank You @bryan60. It worked .Here can I use Behavior subject or subject ?

Answer (score 1):

To set the default value on edit click, the can use `FormBuilderConfiguration` of ***@rxweb/reactive-form-validators*** in which you can set the value coming from edit api call in `defaultValue` property like this:

```
 setItemData()
    {
           let user = new User();
         var formBuilderConfig = new FormBuilderConfiguration();
        formBuilderConfig.propsConfig = {'RequestNo':{defaultValue:"abc1"},"RequestId":{defaultValue:1}}
         this.editForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.formGroup(user,formBuilderConfig);
    }
```

You need to import `RxReactiveFormsModule` in app component

Here is the complete component code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormArray } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxFormBuilder,RxFormGroup,FormBuilderConfiguration } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

import { User, } from './user.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user',
    templateUrl: './patch-complete.component.html'
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    editForm: RxFormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        let user = new User();
        this.editForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.formGroup(user); 
         // this.itemData = this.sharepointService.itemData 
    // In console, I can see the details of the itemData but not able to set to the formcontrols.
    }
 
    setItemData()
    {
           let user = new User();
         var formBuilderConfig = new FormBuilderConfiguration();
        formBuilderConfig.propsConfig = {'RequestNo':{defaultValue:"abc1"},"RequestId":{defaultValue:1}}
         this.editForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.formGroup(user,formBuilderConfig);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>

   <form [formGroup]= "editForm">
  <label> DefaultRequestNo </label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="RequestNo">
<br/>
   <label> DefaultRequestID </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="RequestId">
    <br/>
<button (click)="setItemData()">SetItemData</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1vtlr?file=src/app/patch-complete.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to set the defaults manually instead of letting the FormBuilder manage them. You should try modifying your code above to:

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   RequestNo : [data.Request_x0020_Number],
   RequestId : [data.Request_x0020_ID]
})
```

That should work.